# How to customize Opentip default styles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, opentip

I am working on implementing tool tip using opentip framework,  Since  I am very new  to Jquery and Java script I have implemented using Opentip HTML attributes but need to change its styles like tip joint and its background color..

can someone help me out...Find my code below thanks

```css
#tooltip2{padding: 13px 0px 0px 10px;margin: -1px 4px -4px -5px !important;"}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/enyo/opentip/master/downloads/opentip-jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/enyo/opentip/master/css/opentip.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option" style="width:13%;float:left;">
<label style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;" id="tooltip2" data-ot="This is my new tooltip" data-ot-delay="1" data-ot-hide-trigger="closeButton" data-ot-style="glass" data-ot-fixed="true"  data-ot-tipJoint="'left, middle'">Option1</label>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to move you jQuery script tag to before the opentip script tag.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/enyo/opentip/master/downloads/opentip-jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/enyo/opentip/master/css/opentip.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

You can set the tip joint using the data-ot-tip-joint attribute (notice that every capital letter in an option name becomes preceded by a hyphen when it becomes an attribute). You don't actually need the single quotes around value, nor the comma and nor the middle if you just want the middle

```
data-ot-tip-joint="left"
```

will set the tip joint to the left center of your tooltip. You should have enough (and a bit more) space to fit the tooltip - so, if your target is on the top of your view port and you do a 'left center' tip joint, it may automatically become a 'left top' because there's not enough space.

You set the background using the background attribute

```
data-ot-background="red"
```

You full HTML should be

```
<div class="option" style="width:13%;float:left;margin-top: 100px">
    <label style="padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;" id="tooltip2" data-ot="This is my new tooltip" data-ot-delay="1" data-ot-hide-trigger="closeButton" data-ot-style="glass" data-ot-fixed="true" data-ot-tip-joint="left" data-ot-background="red">Option1</label>
</div>
```

I've added a top margin just to prove that it will appear with the configured tip joint IF there is space.